# RunTime.IMportModuleError "AWS lambdas"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

for some reason when doing "sam deploy" and "sam local start-api" I am getting this error that I have not been able to solve.
Does anyone know what is going on ?

My Lamdba function:

```
const Responses = require('../helpers/Response') 

exports.handler = async( event, context, callback ) => {
    try{
        const userInputs = JSON.parse( event.body );

        return Responses._200({ msg: 'Hello world' })

    }catch(err){
        console.log( err )
        return callback( null, { msg: 'Algo salió mal | leer logs' }
        );
    };
};
```

The module I try to import:

```
const { HttpStatusCode } = require("./HttpStatusCode")

const headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
 
const Responses = {
    _200( data = {} ){
        return{
            headers,
            statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK,
            body: JSON.stringify( data )
        }
    }
};

module.exports = Responses
```

The Output:
Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'errorMessage', 'trace', 'errorType'} in {'errorType': 'Runtime.ImportModuleError', 'errorMessage': "Error: Cannot find module '../helpers/Response'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs", 'trace': ["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '../helpers/Response'", 'Require stack:', '- /var/task/index.js', '- /var/runtime/index.mjs', '    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1000:17)', '    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)', '    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)', '    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1']}

I have already tried to do all possible imports, but that doesn't solve anything.